# Upvoted comment icon is slightly misaligned

Tags: bug, mobile-web, mobile-safari

I've discovered the most trivial bug in the world.

This upvote icon was in line with the others until I tapped it to upvote the comment:

[image]

It's now *slightly* off kilter.

This is on MSE in mobile safari on iOS 8.0.

Comment: Same in Chrome on Android 5. All upvoted triangles are slightly to the left, dark (upvoted by me) and white (not upvoted by me).